# iOS drag and drop from icloud is not on disk - how to force download?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag-and-drop from the `Files` app onto a custom view in an iOS 15 swiftui application. I'm currently working on the iPad simulator, and only working with `.audio` files at the moment.

If the file is local, drag-and-drop works fine - the drop delegate picks up the URL of the file dropped, and we can copy it where ever. *However*, when I drag-and-drop a file from my iCloud drive that hasn't been downloaded to the device, I can see the URL, but obviously, the file doesn't exist on disk for me to use.

Is there a way for me to force the file to be downloaded to the device before drag, to be able to use it as if it was any other file? If I bring up a file-chooser interface, and select the non-downloaded file, the usual spinner comes up while the file is being downloaded to the device to use *before* the handler is invoked - then it is invoked with the URL of the now-local file.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Edit: To be clear, I'm strictly talking about forcing iOS to download the file locally from the `Files` app before being available as a draggable item. I'd prefer not to force it to download once the drop handler receives it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is closed as unfocused - it asks a specific question about a specific interaction pattern on iOS. What is unfocused about it? I'll be happy to make it more focused and clear, but in my opinion, the ask is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: myUrl)`. See [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410377-startdownloadingubiquitousitem) for more info.

Comment: Hey thanks for that! I will do that, but then I have to keep download state on my side (progress, errors, etc). I was hoping there was some way to tell the drag _source_ to download it to disk before it even got to my code, especially from the `Files` app. But I guess if there was another drag source, i'd need to be able to tell every source to do so? In any case, thanks for the link!